# beam.io.WriteToText writes 0 bytes to the destination file?

Tags: python-3.x, apache

I have a simple apache beam pipeline which reads bigquery >> creates a parquet file in GCS >> From the GCS path, I read the metadata information and yield a JSON object with a custom ParDo function >> I write as text back to the GCS.

There is no runtime error but, when I check the file created in the destination GCS path, it has **0 bytes**.
I checked the whether the **Pcollection** is empty by using the **beam.ParDo(print)** function. When I do this it prints the JSON object. I already tried convert the object as str, list and dict. Everything works well with the **beam.ParDo(print)** statement but fails to write any data to GCS.
Please let me know, what is my mistake? Thanks in advance :)

````
class CreateMetadata(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        # element here gets a GCS path as gs://.....
        ### Some internal process ###
        # This function is called only once at the end of the internal 
        # process have a JSON object as entity data
        yield entity_data

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    table = (
        pipeline | 'ReadTableFromBigQuery' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=bigquery.read_sql(query_string=query),
                                                                                  use_standard_sql=True))
        | 'writeAsParquetToGCS' >> pq.WriteToParquet(OUTPUT, schema=bigquery.get_parquet_schema_from_bq(),
                                                     num_shards=1)
        | 'CreateMetadata' >> beam.ParDo(CreateMetadata())
        # | beam.ParDo(print)

        | 'WriteToGCS' >> beam.io.WriteToText(file_path_prefix=OUTPUT.replace('Some GCS path'), file_name_suffix='.json',num_shards=1)
        # Now after the pipeline runs when I check the GCS path there is a file created with 
        # 0 bytes???

    )```
````

Comment: Hi, I am joining late to this post, have you get a solution for this?